# Color in javascript - how to build the CSS

Tags: javascript

I need to build options of color and then according to the option to get the color.
For example if the color is in size 1 to get some color if the order in size 2 to git different colors.

also I want to add not only the colors but more options of CSS
What is the best way to build this list ? Do I need to do it with CSS and then to read the data according to the size ? Do I need to build the CSS with class ?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence *"For example if the color is in size 1 to get some color if the order in size 2 to git different colors"*... how can colours have a size?

Comment: I dont understand it at all :-)

Comment: Do you want a select option list with colored options and the value of each option is equals to its HEX color code?

Comment: Apparently he wants to build a collection of color sets, where he can choose a particular set and then change the color of something with a given color from that set with JavaScript.

Comment: does he want to build classes with CSS properties and assign them to the DOM objects? I don't think I get his issue.. Is it supposed to be dynamic generation of CSS classes?

Comment: Thanks for the help the idea that I have a key for the colors for example size and according to the size I can know to choose the right color for example if the size is 1 I want to choose red color , if the size is 2 I want to choose yellow color , the CSS should not be dynamic but the choose of the CSS should be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everyone else, I'm not exactly sure what you're after. But here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8NX7/) that may be a start :)

Here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/UUPdv/).